Docker image fails to locate entrypoint.sh script
I'm trying to build a custom Docker image using saucelabs/sauce-connect:5.2.0 as the base. I want to include a custom entrypoint.sh script that prints a message and then starts Sauce Connect with the appropriate arguments.
Here's my Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Prepare the entrypoint script
FROM alpine:3.17 as builder
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Stage 2: Use Sauce Connect as the base image
FROM saucelabs/sauce-connect:5.2.0
COPY --from=builder /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

And here’s my entrypoint.sh (simplified for this example):
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting Sauce Connect Proxy..."

I build the image like this:
docker build -t sauce-connect-custom .

And run it with:
docker run \
  -e SAUCE_USERNAME="my-username" \
  -e SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY="my-access-key" \
  -e SAUCE_TUNNEL_NAME="my-tunnel" \
  -e SAUCE_REGION="us-west" \
  -it sauce-connect-custom

However, I get this error when I try to run the container:
exec /entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

What I've Tried:

Verified that the entrypoint.sh file exists in the same directory as the Dockerfile
Checked the permissions of entrypoint.sh (it's executable: -rwxr-xr-x)
Rebuilt the image without cache using docker build --no-cache -t sauce-connect-custom .
Inspected the container by running docker run -it sauce-connect-custom sh and checking for /entrypoint.sh (it doesn't exist in the final image)

The base image saucelabs/sauce-connect:5.2.0 is a lightweight image likely built on a minimal Linux distribution. I suspect the issue might be related to /bin/sh compatibility or the build context.
How can I ensure that my entrypoint.sh script is properly copied into the final image and executed when the container starts? Any suggestions for debugging or fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

The shell needs to exist, so you'll need a different base image. And if it does, then the next likely cause is a Windows linefeed in the shell script, i.e. looking for a binary called /bin/sh^M.

The linked question was due to line endings. That's not the issue here. People are so quick to mark as duplicate and don't really care about helping OP. I hate that about SO :(

The saucelabs/sauce-connect:5.2.0 image doesn't contain a shell.
The error message exec /entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory is a little confusing because what it means is that /bin/sh, the program specified in the first line of your script, doesn't exist.
There's no obligation for an image to contain a shell and some choose to not include it either because of image size concerns or security concerns.
